# Navigations with different styles after reloading a page

Tags: css

I am working on my website ( http://idefinland.com ) and have problem with displaying navigation. It looks good in all browsers and with any resolutions. Ideally it looks like this:
![Proper navigation][1]

Sometimes in Chrome and Safari navigation drops out of the header. It looks like this:

http://h1964807.stratoserver.net/files/share/9_1_2012/XxtmQqaFD0a0tEqylkdg.jpg

Then I reload the page and the problem disappear.

Has anyone ideas on what could be a reasons for such a problem?

Comment: Is the HTML / DOM the same when the error appears and after the page reload?

Comment: HTML / DOM looks the same. Thanks for issue with styles.

Answer (score 1):

Read the directions in [footer.css](http://www.idefinland.com/wp-content/themes/ide%20finland/styles/footer.css) -- there's some code you need to put in your HTML file to fully enable this stylesheet. Specifically, this needs to go between the `<head>..</head>` tags:

```
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it did not solve the problem.
What else do you think could be done?

Comment: I admit I'm stuck, since I can't reproduce the problem myself. One idea I had was to replace all the absolute URLs in your stylesheet links to relative URLs, which might make them load sooner.